# How to retrieve output from an .exe file when called in a Java program?

Tags: java, parameters, exe

In my Java program, I call an .exe program using this code:
`Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\PathToExe\\MyExe.exe").start();`
I pass parameters to it. How do I retrieve the output from the .exe so I can store it in a String[]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve any input and/or output of your program by using:

1. [java.lang.Process.getErrorStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream()) to retrieve the error output (stderr)
2. [java.lang.Process.getInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()) to retrieve the input stream you can write to (stdin)
3. [java.lang.Process.getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream()) to retrieve the output stream (the regular output of the program) (stdout)